# is there a Graph API version of the old links.preview REST method?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, preview

I'm writing a web application that allows users to post status messages to Facebook, along with the usual link sharing option.

Before the REST API was deprecated, I would have used the [links.preview method](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/rest/links.preview/) to retrieve Facebook's preview of the linked page. (title, description, image) What would I use in the Graph API?

I used the [object debugger](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=http://spaceup.org/) to turn a URL into the right Graph API ID for a link preview:

https://graph.facebook.com/10150260487553402

...but I can't find any way of turning a URL into that ID from the API itself. Any ideas?

Comment: Doesn't the Object properties from the Debug tool do that - it will show you the preview of what facebook will share on the timeline and newsfeed.

Comment: @deesarus The web debug tool does show that, but is there a Graph API call to do the same thing?

Comment: If it's an Open Graph action, you will be able to preview the news feed stories. Refer to the Previewing stories section here - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/tutorial/

Comment: @deesarus Thanks for the link. Unfortunately, I need a preview of an external website, not an Open Graph action.

Answer (score 0):

there is no graph equivalent to link.preview.  the only way to 'preview' a post before it is made is to scrape the link yourself for it's metadata (title, description, image_src) and show the preview that way.

if you have a title, description, and image for what you are sharing you could just pass them as parameters to override the defaults and force it to look the way you specify.

Comment: Do we have additional update on this? Chrish, are you able to solve the problem, if so, can you please post the same for other's benefits. I am also looking for similar one.